# Contact form not sending to client

Tags: php, html, forms, smtp, contacts

I have an issue with a contact form I have set up on a clients site, the form posts to my email address no problem but doesn't for my client who's domain is registered through 123 reg and email accounts are set up within Gmail. On contacting my web host they have suggested using SMTP, this is something I have never used before, I have googled this but haven't came to any light. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Melissa

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {
$to = 'hello@email.co.uk'; //change this to suit your admin email address
$subject = 'Website enquiry'; //change this to the mail subject you want the admin to receive

$expected = array('name', 'email', 'tel', 'message1'); //list all of the fields in the form
$required = array('name', 'email', 'message1'); //list the required fields in the form
$missing = array();

$suspect = false;
$pattern = '/Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';

function isSuspect($val, $pattern, &$suspect) {
if (is_array($val)) {
  foreach ($val as $item) {
    isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);
    }
  }
else {
  if (preg_match($pattern, $val)) {
    $suspect = true;
    }
  }
}

isSuspect($_POST, $pattern, $suspect);

if ($suspect) {
$mailSent = false;
unset($missing);
}
else {
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
  if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {
    array_push($missing, $key);
    }
  elseif (in_array($key, $expected)) {
    ${$key} = $temp;
    }
  }
}

if (!empty($email)) {
$checkEmail = '/^[^@]+@[^\s\r\n\'";,@%]+$/';
if (!preg_match($checkEmail, $email)) {
  array_push($missing, 'email');
  }
}


if (!$suspect && empty($missing)) { 

    $message .= "Name: $name\n\n";
    $message .= "Email address: $email\n\n";
    $message .= "Telephone number: $tel\n\n";
    $message .= "Message: $message1\n\n";

    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

    $additionalHeaders = "From: $email";

    $complete = mail($to, $subject, $message, $additionalHeaders);
    if ($complete) {
      unset($missing);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Below shows the form:

```
<?php 
                if ($_POST && isset($missing)) {
                    echo'<p class="warning">Please complete the missing or incorrect fields.</p>';
                }
                if ($_POST && isset($complete)) {
                    echo '<p class="green"><strong>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch soon.</strong></p>';
                }
                else{?>


                <form method="post" action="" id="contact_form" class="validate">

                    <fieldset>

                        <legend>Your Details</legend>

                        <label for="name"><b>Full Name</b></label>
                        <input name="name" placeholder="John Smith" class="" <?php if (isset($missing)) {echo 'value="'.htmlentities($_POST['name']).'"';} ?> />
                        <br>
                        <label for="email"><b>Email Address</b></label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="hello@shnuggle.com" class="" <?php if (isset($missing)) {echo 'value="'.htmlentities($_POST['email']).'"';} ?> />
                        <br>
                        <label for="phone"><b>Phone Number <span class="note">(optional)</span></b></label>
                        <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="+44 (0)28 9012 3456" class="" <?php if (isset($missing)) {echo 'value="'.htmlentities($_POST['tel']).'"';} ?> />
                        <br>
                        <legend>Your Message</legend>

                        <textarea name="message1" <?php if (isset($missing)) {echo 'value="'.htmlentities($_POST['message1']).'"';} ?> />Hello,</textarea>

                    </fieldset>

                    <!--<button type="submit" class="btn submit"><span class="icon">m</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Send Message</button>-->
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
                    <button type="reset" class="btn reset">Clear form</button>

                </form>
                <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Work !!
If you got Error undefined Variable on 54 line
than convert

```
 $message .= "Name: $name\n\n";
```

to

```
 $message = "Name: $name\n\n";
```